# Write translation of some words just below them with Paragraph of reportlab.platypus

Tags: python, pdf-generation, reportlab

I have a specific use case of reportlab library of python.
I want to write  automatically a translation of some words just below them as in the following image.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/X08n6.png)

I used pdfgen, it worked, it is rigid and difficult because calculate manually the position of words and the text is so long.
I want to  do this with Paragraph of platypus, but I don't see how.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.